# Best complex analysis references?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I own Gamelin's 'Complex Analysis', but I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding it.  I have also tried watching MIT Open Courseware videos on the subject, but I easily get lost.  Are there any references (**preferably NOT textbooks** as I am short on funds at the moment) that server as a smooth transition from calculus to complex analysis?  I have been lucky to have some help from a user on this website, but I would also like some other references so I don't constantly take up his time.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course in a strict sense this is Ahlfors.

Comment: @Herbert: Ahlfors may not be expensive everywhere. I bought an Indian edition last week for Rs. 250 (approx. 4 USD)!

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, really. The publisher "Tata McGrawHill Education" has taken tp publishing Indian editions of many "standard" textbooks - cheap paperbacks, but they are a real boon for students, I should think.

Comment: Here is a textbook that is freely available online: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/complex.html

Answer (score 4):

1) Ahlfors is the best

2) Conway's GTM11,159

3) GTM122,172

4).  also, I recommend Freitag's 'complex analysis'(Spring Universitext)

5). Henri Cartan, Elementary Theory of analytic functions of one or several complex variables

6).Elias M.Stein&Rami Shakarchi, Complex analysis

7).Raghavan Narasimhan&Yves Nievergelt, Complex analysis in complex variable, second edition

8). M. A. Lavrentieff & B. V. Shabat, Methods of  Functions of a complex variable, Sixth Edition

**last but not least**
9). Kunihiko Kodaira, Complex analysis

Answer (score 2):

Here are some books that I would recommend (in decreasing order):

- Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* : This is a really lovely book if you want to look at pictures and waft through the basics without getting too worried about the nitty-gritty.
- E.T. Copson's *Introduction to the theory of functions of one complex variable* : The book is somewhat dated, but I learnt quite a lot from it and I really liked the author's style.
- L.V. Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis* : This is the bible. Never leave home without it.
- D'Angelo's *An Introduction to Complex Analysis and Geometry* : These are some notes the author wrote for a course meant for "bright freshman students". It is available online [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jpda/). I haven't used it myself, but it looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations!  Are thee any references in addition to these books that you recommend as well?

Comment: Two more, Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable* and Stein/Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* - but these are graduate level textbooks, so be warned.

Comment: Also Ablowitz _Complex variables: introduction and applications_.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try:

[Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985921) by Serge Lang

mainly because it has an accompanying problems and solutions manual:

[Problems and Solutions for Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387988319) by Rami Shakarchi

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated that you need a transition from calculus to complex analysis, it would probably be best to start with an application-oriented text (i.e. no graduate-level analysis).
You could try [Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering, Science, and Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0139078746).