# Texts for Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am interested in reading about complex dynamics, Riemann surfaces, and related subjects, but I lack complex analysis as a prerequisite. I want a text that is rigorous and challenging (e.g. not a complex variables text focusing on computation), but nevertheless a good introduction to the subject. Ideally, being interested in some of the more geometric and topological sides of the subject, I would like something that has more of a topological flavor to it, e.g. assumes a knowledge of metric spaces and basic topology.

I considered Ahlfors, but I am skeptical as to whether this would actually be ideal for one's first exposure to the subject. Does anyone know of any other texts I could consider that would suit me?

As for my background, the most advanced analysis books I have read are Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and the single-variable half of Rudin's Principles.

Thanks!

Comment: Lang's complex analysis book is pretty basic and would serve as a good introduction to the subject before moving on to something more advanced like Ahlfors.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789284/best-complex-analysis-references/789316

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks for the recommendation. I see that he includes a second part on geometric function theory, which is appealing. I'll consider this.

Comment: Presumably you have already looked through the current literature on complex analytic dynamics, but what about an older review? Link: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183551835 , I thought this was fairly good and it leads you to what you need to know. Wikipedia also has translations of Fatou and Julia's original papers.Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Julia

Comment: I have read some expositions on the subject, but not any current research (or anything very advanced in general), as I figured I lacked the prerequisites (namely complex analysis). But I have recently become very interested in the subject, so I hope to be able to study some of the current literature soon in the future. Thanks for the link, though; I will bookmark it and try reading through it sometime soon.

Comment: Check out John Milnor on Arxiv  , there are a number of interesting papers, he has the spirit of the subject. He does many "computer experiments" and  his usual brilliant expository style will get you over some bumps if feel your weakness right now is in Complex Analysis. Link: http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Milnor_J/0/1/0/all/0/1http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Milnor_J/0/1/0/all/0/1  he also wrote a book on the subject , but this is available right now.